# How to identify the tones in Chinese text?

Tags: chinese-locale, pinyin

Is there a programmatic way to identify the tones in Chinese text?

For an input string like `苹果` I need to extract the tones as `2` and `3` as it would be indicated in the pinyin transliteration `píng guǒ` or `ping2 guo3`.

I guess a possible workaround would be converting Chinese hanzi text to pinyin (e.g. with [pinyin4j](https://github.com/belerweb/pinyin4j)) and then extract the tones from pinyin, but I assume there must be a better and direct way to do it.

#### *Context*

The question is about if there is some algorithmic way to identify the tones or if *the only way* is a map lookup against an authoritative source e.g. the publicly available [CEDICT database](https://www.mdbg.net/chinese/dictionary?page=cedict).

Comment: perhaps this might be something you're looking for? https://github.com/sxei/pinyinjs It does include a getTone() function

Comment: I'm a native speaker, and I doubt that it's possible. Chinese character can have multiple tones depending on the context. The only reliable way to do this is to call some APIs with the full context.

Comment: @KaiHao: so, if I understand you correctly this means that there is no algorithm that can be used to 'convert' hanzi to tone info, and therefore one _must_ use a mechanism similar to what pinyin converters do: segment hanzi to known character groups, then to single characters and then look them up in a map, right?

Comment: @ccpizza That's correct. Since you can't be sure what tone the character is just by judging it individually, there's no such "algorithm" to map them to their tones. For instance, "一" can be tone 1, 2, 4, or neutral depending on the context.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm a native speaker, and I doubt that it's possible. Chinese character can have multiple tones depending on the context. The only reliable way to do this is to call some APIs with the full context.

Since you can't be sure what tone the character is just by judging it individually, there's no such "algorithm" to map them to their tones.

For instance, "一" can be tone 1, 2, 4, or neutral depending on the context.

Comment: Based on your response I conclude that the approach is building a tone map based on existing pinyin data starting with the longest segments, for example, https://github.com/belerweb/pinyin4j/blob/master/src/main/resources/pinyindb/multi_pinyin.txt and then process the remaining individual characters e.g. using this map: https://github.com/belerweb/pinyin4j/blob/master/src/main/resources/pinyindb/unicode_to_hanyu_pinyin.txt. Or use the cedict-based mapping that can be generated with scripts from  https://github.com/mozillazg/phrase-pinyin-data.

Comment: @ccpizza That would be a great start! The best solution, however, is to use an existing trained API. Pre-defined maps are not gonna cover all cases. For instance, "分校" can both be "fen1 xiao4" and "fen1 jiao4" depending on the context. This is a rather rare case though, and even well-trained APIs could be wrong about that either.

Comment: you are right; in my tests I have seen that all static pinyin conversion libraries (that I know of) have an error rate of ~10% as described in this question https://chinese.stackexchange.com/questions/40284/examples-of-correct-and-incorrect-pinyin and in the links in the answers. It can be reduced to some degree by extending the phrases file (i.e. the `multi_pinyin.txt` in pinyin4j) but that still leaves at least a 5%+ error rate (mostly with tones). ..for the time being a static map would be good enough for my use case.